# Is this sequence uniformly bounded in $L^\infty(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $u \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ on a bounded domain $\Omega$. Let $w_j$ be the eigenfuntions of the Neumann Laplacian.

Is it true that 
$$a_n := \sum_{i=1}^n (u,w_j)w_j$$
is such that $\lVert a_n\rVert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \leq C$ uniformly in $n$?

I've no clue why but I think answer is.